# Meaning and grammatical structure of this sentence

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

Can anyone clarify the meaning and grammatical structure of this sentence, which is about Wanda Landowska?

> Her playing was Romantic, but it was at least as close in spirit to the style of playing intended by composers of the Baroque (1600–1750) and Classical (1750–1830) eras, as have been the more exacting but less emotionally resonant interpretations of most harpsichordists since Landowska.

I am interested specifically in knowing what the wording "as have been the more exacting but less emotionally resonant interpretations of most harpsichordists since Landowska" is intended to convey.

Comment: Specifically the part ", as have been the more exacting but less emotionally resonant interpretations of most harpsichordists since Landowska." - which it is implying actually?

Answer (score 3):

You could break it into individual parts for easier understanding:

1. Her playing was Romantic (although apparently she played Baroque and Classical compositions).
2. Most harpsichordists since her time played in a style that was more exacting, but less emotional.
3. Comparing the two, her style was at least as close to the composers' intentions as theirs.

Comment: This article on the performance of Baroque music [link](http://www.baroquemusic.org/barperf.html), especially the harpsichord section, may be useful in further clarifying the content of the passage.